Update index buffer in Vulkan at run-time
What is the proper way to update at run-time the index buffer in Vulkan?
Many thanks

Most basically, you'd need to set a fence/other synchronization to make sure that the index buffer isn't being used, then map it (vkMapMemory), copy any changes over, then unmap it.

Many thanks for the answer. I have some answers to ask you.
Do I need to create a temporary staging buffer and a new Index buffer or I have to reuse the old index buffer ?  The map, copy and unmap operations are done on the index buffer ?
Many thanks

Mapping is re-using the buffer but you can choose either/both options. swapping does reduce the need for fences/synchronization, however you will have to keep track of the buffer to make sure you don't leak it
